# How fix slow problem in react native with expo camera in android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have problems taking pictures with Expo Camera. In ios runs well, Android shows a lot in photography. (5 seconds)

What is the difference in performance?

I am occupying EXPO V: 56.0.0

I try passing it as parameter `skipProcessing: true` to function takePictureAsync

```
snap = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      this.camera.takePictureAsync().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
              imageuri: data.uri
            })
        })
      };
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Have you tried looking at open issues on the Expo camera project on Github? There seems to be a long-running issue related to `takePictureAsync` being slow, check it out here https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/706

Comment: In reference thread talk about the same solution i tried.  add parameter `skipProcessing : true` to function takePictureAsync. And still wont work.

Comment: That is only one of the options suggested in the thread. This comment has another thought on the topic https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/706#issuecomment-397824679 . You also should make sure you are using a version of the Expo SDK that contains the fix, the version (assuming 56.0.0 was supposed to be the version) is not listed as an Expo SDK version on their site https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk